# Fix Razer Barracuda AC-1 audio card software on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

As there's no Windows 8 installer, I installed the Windows 7 version in Windows 7 compatibility mode successfully. (Booted with Driver Signature Enforcement disabled because I'm on 64-bit.) However, launching the configuration application immediately crashes before opening. Is there a solution? I already tried the Vista installer. I may have had a similar issue on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Windows 7 "compatibility" version installed on Windows 8 and notice the software fails to launch, following these steps. First uninstall the Razer audio card from *Programs and Features* (`appwiz.cpl`). Then uninstall the device and select to delete driver files from *Device Manager* (`devmgmt.msc`). (This may be optional, I haven't tested.)

If you're on 64-bit Windows, [disable driver signature enforcement](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/).

Install the [Vista version](http://drivers.razersupport.com//index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=107&pcid=9&nav=0,78,9) in Vista [compatibility mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10436/using-program-compatibility-mode-in-windows-7/) so that the installer will run. The software should now work correctly. If it still fails to launch you may wish to verify the *Razer Barracuda AC-1 Gaming Audio Card* folder is properly deleted from Program Files when uninstalling.

Comment: Nice work around until razer release drivers, most solutions leave it at install vista drivers

Comment: Razer ceased support for AC-1, so the only solution is installing the generic C-Media drivers since AC-1 is using the C-Media Oxygen HD CMI8788 chip, which is already mentioned in @untore post

Comment: @NikolaD Well not really "the only solution", seeing as the solution you're commenting on works fine. :-P May well be the only solution going into the future though... the next big OS version.

Comment: No, what I wanted to say actually, is that this is the only officially supported windows 8 solution (these are the only real Win 8 drivers). :) Of course, any other solution that works without causing the problem is fully valid

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Thanks. I wonder if the actual driver is any different or if it's just packaged differently. (I wonder the same about Razer's.) But I'm too lazy to investigate. I'll probably +1/accept untore's answer then unless Oxygen's control panel lacks major features or something, will have to see.

Answer (score 1):

Found a better solution, well, actually I did not, after installed windows 8.1, I found in the tray icon the software, then I looked it up.

[C-Media Electronics **Oxygen HD CMI8788** generic Windows 8 drivers](http://www.cmedia.com.tw/EN/DownloadCenter_Detail/pserno-37.html)

Everything works fine, the only thing missing is that "Distance" feature, or maybe it is in there too and I have not found it, anyway everything works.

Plus it does not have that switch resolution bug that each version of the razer control panel had.

Comment: Hey nice! The distance feature is actually very useful. This is easier to do but if it lacks features I'll stick with the simple repair of the Razer control panel I posted. Great to know what it's based on, maybe all the options are in there, just hiding.

Comment: Well, the closest to razer ESP could be this : http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/3460/k4bl.png

The thing is that I don't know what this ESP actually does, I mean, can you tell the difference in a game? Basically it should increase the volume of further sounds...This is a thing that always boggled my mind about razer AC-1 soundcard, this and the alleged benefits of the HD-DAI connector.

Comment: Oh hey thanks for the image. I was referring to this, that lets you set the volume for individual speakers: http://imgur.com/IC01WSh That way you can calibrate it correctly for exactly where your chair/couch is in the room. Does the Oxygen control panel have that?

Comment: Yes it does indeed, the thing is, the link I actually posted does not let you install the drivers, because the setup does not recognize the sound card, this panel appears only after the latest windows installation, which is weird.

Comment: http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/7384/89v4.png

Comment: I finally found the time to try this out. How did you get the software to run? Are you on a 32-bit OS? (I'm on 64-bit.) The installers didn't recognize the card but I was able to browse & force install the driver. (Installers still don't recognize sadly.) Also tried executing each program in "Program" folder as administrator, but it's a no go.

Comment: Or maybe that automatically installed 8.1 version is different than the download somehow or for some reason doesn't like 8.